# Windows Cordova / Ionic app white screen after release build

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I developed a Cordova/ionic Universal Windows app. Everything works perfectly in debug mode in the simulator and a real device. After i make a release build (Store -> Create app packages...) and start the release build or start a new debug session the app starts a "about:blank" page after the splash screen has disappeared. I have to run "ionic build windows" again to see my app. I hope anyone is familiar with this problem, its driving me crazy!

Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI version: 1.7.14
Ionic app lib version: 0.7.0

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I am still having this issue using Cordova CLI 6.3.0 Ionic 1.3.1 and Windows Cordova 4.4.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have same issue with ionic windows universal app, but it works well with windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1  any solution found for windows universal app ?

Comment: I had the same issue. This post helped me to resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200592/visual-studio-2015-cordova-windows-10-blank-white-screen-after-associated-with