# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Windows 10 > Blank/white screen after associated with the existing windows store app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

Without associating the app with the store, i can run and debug the cordova app on my devices (all works fine). But after associating the app with the store (or after built a package for the store), the app starts and i get a white screen, no errors in visual studio!

I have installed the update 3 and tried to run in release mode, but no success.
No errors occur.

I Use:
- Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3
- Node Version 4.5.0
- Cordova Version 6.3.1
- and release the app for windows 10

========================

I found out that the package name was changed after assocating with store.
So i changed the package name at the start page option to the new one in the appxmanifest.

After that the app starts and i see my page, but with many errors, i cant interact now.

Here the errors:

- JavaScript runtime error: 'Windows' is undefined cordova.js (1559,13)
- deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
- Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
- Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

from the debugger:

- "WWAHost.exe" (Skript): "Skriptcode (MSAppHost/3.0)" geladen.
- Es wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst: in Zeile 596, Spalte 9 in ms-appx-web://........./www/WinJS/js/base.js
  0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference
- Ausnahmefehler in Zeile 1559, Spalte 13 in ms-appx-web://......../www/cordova.js
  0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Windows' is undefined

Who can help me?

Kevin

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue.
In fact, when we associate app with the store, association change "Package Name" with name generated to the store.
The result is : start page don't know where is "index.html" because package name changed.

To resolve it, cordova team added two preferences :

```
<preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="12225TOTO42.3355241V9C2T6" />
<preference name="WindowsStorePublisherName" value="CN=9985D2C8-IUI5-4272-TOTO-EBR6FE26877A" />
```

You just have to add it to your config.xml and fill fields with your app identity informations (retrieve this values from App Management --> App Identity in the Dev Center)

Association should be successful now !

The issue reference is here : https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/506

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I resolve it now.
When you associate the application to store, Visual Studio changes these values:

[image]

but it does not change the value of package name in the application tab:

[image]

so the index.html is not found and the app shows a blank screen. 
To resolve it, you must add two preferences in config.xml file as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658027/2496666

and rebuild the project from CLI with the usual command:

```
cordova build windows
```

after rebuild the project, the values shown in the following image must be the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution!

The error only occur, when i install cordova and plugins over CLI, but when
i start a cordova project over visual studio 2015 and use the integrated plugin manager -> so it works without any error.

Kevin

Comment: I run into the same issue. This does not make any sense! What if you want\need to use the CLI for plugin management? Why does this happen only after Store Association? I'm not sure if it's a cordova-windows issue, or it is just Visual Studio fault.
Can you post the steps for the resolution?

Comment: Hi,

you also can manage the plugins with visual studio, you do not need cli.

kevin

Answer (score 0):

before associate app in visual studio

ionic plarform add windows

cordova build -- --packageCertificateKeyFile="CordovaApp.Windows10_StoreKey.pfx" --packageThumbprint="8d66824...."

and you have associated app without visual studio